# Is there any way to see traffic sources to a GitHub project?

Tags: github, analytics

A lot of people just starred one of my GitHub projects overnight (yay!).

Is there any way for me to figure out where this influx of traffic came from?

Does GitHub provide any kind of analytics?

Comment: It is now possible to view incoming sources of traffic

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's now a baked in feature under the [GitHub Traffic section](https://github.com/blog/1672-introducing-github-traffic-analytics).

> You can now see detailed analytics data for repositories that you're an owner of or that you can push to. Just load up the graphs page for your particular repository and you'll see a new link to the traffic page.

The old method used to be some hack like adding an image or similar web bug to your README file.

When someone comes across your repo, provided your [README has an extension that GitHub will automatically render](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo), then it should also load the image. And that should, depending on how the web bug is set up, give you some detail or clue as to the source of traffic.

Or you could appeal via contact to [the GitHub Supportocats](https://help.github.com/contact) and see if they're willing to give you a heads up on the incoming source of the sauce.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the update!

Comment: any way to see more than current month?

Answer (score 16):

[Bitdeli](https://bitdeli.com/free) provides a free badge that you can add to your READMEs in GitHub. It will give you access to the full request logs, which allows you to analyze who has been viewing your repositories.

Answer (score 5):

[githalytics](http://githalytics.com/) provides some basic analytics.  I don't think it would tell you about your traffic sources though.

Answer (score 0):

[BitDeli](http://bitdeli.com) had a solution for this, based on a badge image connected to your BitDeli account.

The idea was to add it on the markdown of your readme file on GitHub. But it is not working anymore.

On the other hand, the statistics that GitHub shows by its own, just show information of last 15 days visit...

Answer (score 0):

Analytics for GitHub - helps you to see traffic for your public repositories

Join Google+ Community to try the app:
https://plus.google.com/communities/106373382024164307474

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click *Insights* > *Graphs*:

[image]

Then, *Traffic*:

[image]